# Expression to Remove Last URL link from Text in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I would like to remove the url which occur last in a string

Input

> Hey All the Best. https://google.com/last

Output

> Hey All the Best.

Input

> Thank you for making me touch 3 Million. https://google.com/first. It’s not MY achievement... it’s your LOVE. https://google.com/second. Gratitude forever https://google.com/last

Output

> Thank you for making me touch 3 Million. https://google.com/first. It’s not MY achievement... it’s your LOVE. https://google.com/second. Gratitude forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
$str = "Thank you for making me touch 3 Million. https://google.com/first. It’s not MY achievement... it’s your LOVE. https://google.com/second. Gratitude forever https://google.com/last";
//$str = "Hey All the Best. https://google.com/last";
$p = "/(https?:\/\/[^\/]+(?:[\d\w\/\._]*)\s*)$/i";
$result = preg_replace($p, '', $str);
var_dump($result);
```

The '$' in the regular expression is the last match, and if '$' is not added, all links will be matched out. Corresponding to this is '^', matching the beginning.

Comment: While this may answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include a bit of explanation about how this works. A code block by itself is not immediately useful to those who might come across the same issue later on.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. @Hoppeduppeanut

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do:

```
https?://\S+(?!.*https?://\S+)
```